# How can I distinguish two queries in Hibernate depending on a property?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Is there a way in hibernate to select a query depending on a property in the *.hbm.xml file?

For example, if I've two queries in my **MyHibernateFile.hbm.xml** like:

```
<sql-query name="myQuery_1">
    <return-scalar column="idTable1" type="string"/>
    <return-scalar column="descTable1" type="string"/>
    SELECT DISTINCT ID_TABLE AS IDTABLE1, DESC_TABLE AS DESCTABLE1
    FROM ${databaseSchema}.TABLE1
</sql-query>

<sql-query name="myQuery_2">
    <return-scalar column="idTable2" type="string"/>
    <return-scalar column="descTable2" type="string"/>
    SELECT DISTINCT ID_TABLE AS IDTABLE2, DESC_TABLE AS DESCTABLE2
    FROM ${databaseSchema}.TABLE2
</sql-query>
```

Assuming that I have set a property *databaseType* in my java project, can I select the first query if my property ${databaseType} is equal to "DB2" or the second one if ${databaseType} is equal to "ORACLE"? How can I modify **MyHibernateFile.hbm.xml** in order to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. But you can have that conditional within the code of your DAO layer:

```
String queryName = null;
if (databaseType.equals("DB2")) {
   queryName= "myQuery_1";
else if (databaseType.equals("ORACLE")) {
   queryName = "myQuery_2";
}
Query q = session.createNamedQuery(queryName);
```